# R Markdown Footnote in xtable

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm having issues with a footnote not appearing under a table in my R Markdown report.  Below is the code I'm using to process which does successfully but with no footnote appearing under the table.

````
```{r ccxtable7, results="asis", echo=FALSE}
comment <- list(pos = list(0), command = NULL)
comment$pos[[1]] <- c(nrow(indPctChgCC))
comment$command <- c(paste("\\hline\n",
                          "{\\footnotesize Note: * signifies number of 
properties used was 35 or less.}\n", sep = ""))

print(xtable(valPctCon(indPctChgCC, indfreqCC, 35), align = "crrrrr", 
             label = "tab:indCC", add.to.row = comment, hline.after = c(-1,0),
caption = "Industrial Certified-Certified Percentage Change per Value Segment"))
```
````

indPctChCC is a 3x5 matrix of strings.  Could someone help me understand why the footnote is not appearing under the table with this current code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`add.to.row` (and also `hline.after`) are arguments of the `print` function, not `xtable()`.

This should get you where you want:

```
print(xtable(tab, align = "crrr", 
             label = "tab:indCC",
             caption = "Industrial Certified-Certified Percentage Change per Value Segment"), 
      add.to.row = comment, 
      hline.after = c(-1,0))
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! That was silly of me.  It worked after running. Thanks GGamba!